# Using different compression algorithms in java code

Tags: java, algorithm, compression, brotli

I've got a quick question. I have several images, all in bmp format, and I want to incorporate different compression algorithm options into an application I'm writing. I.e., let's say the user selects "Image1.bmp" and wants to compress and export it with either Brotli or JP2K. How could I incorporate those algorithms into their own listener functions so that the image is compressed according to that algorithm? I have the listeners set up and everything, so the only aspect of this problem I need help with is to actually include the algorithms. Is there a plugin I'm unaware of? I've looked a little at GeoTools, but that seems to only be applicable for JP2k.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Edit: I just had a thought. Is there a way that I can effectively run a command line request for certain algorithms from within a java function?

Comment: For running an external command, take a look at the various `exec()` methods of [`java.lang.Runtime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Comment: Use 3rd party libraries or if you've got other programs that can do it, execute them with a `ProcessBuilder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an Interface then create classes to implement the algorithms you want:

```
public interface ICompressionMethods
{
    public void cMethod();
}
```

And then:

```
public class Brotli implements ICompressionMethods
{
    @Override
    public void cMethod()
    {
        // Your compression code here
    }
}
```

Now you need to implement each new different algorithm in a new class.
The benefit of this approach is that you can pass one simple and similiar argument like ICompressionMethod to your methods and yet get different outcomes based on their implementation!

Comment: The use of interfaces is the right way to go, but those names are very unconventional in Java. Perhaps you could change them to `public interface ImageCompressor` and `public void compress()`.

Comment: Hmm...I think something like this will help with organizing my program. I'll definitely give it more thought as to whether or not it's needed. Between this and running exec(), I think I can get this problem solved by the end of the day. Thanks!

Comment: @Sarah Well de-coupled design is always needed. Interfaces give you a lot of power. You can always run `exec` inside one of your implementations of this interface. I think that's the best approach.

Comment: of course @brandon-ibbotson. you can use different names.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson I'm not sure about that in this case. This program likely won't run longer than 600 lines and has limited expandability. It exists so that another development team can quickly compress and compare DICOM images. Then again, I also just don't have the most experience writing my own interfaces. So they make me a tad uncomfortable, both in concept and execution.

Comment: Well, just know that putting `exec` inside an implementation of an interface gives you a lot of flexibility in the future. The nice thing about interfaces is that you can have 20 different implementations and decide which one to use without needing to recompile the rest of the code.

Comment: @Sarah it is always good and mainly preferred to use Interfaces, they are very important parts of Object Oriented Programming.